# Search customers for specific store Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, customer-account, rest-api

I am pulling **customer data** by **email** like below:

```
    $url = "https://www.magento2d.com/rest/storecode/V1/customers/search";
    $filters = "?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=" . urlencode($email) . "&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=equal";
    //$filters2 = "&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_in&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Store%20View&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=equal";
    $response = $this->curlIt("GET", $url . $filters);
    echo $response["total_count"];
```

This, however, seems to pull customers for **both stores**. I tried by setting the **store code** etc in the URL however the same happens and get 2 results for the user in both stores. I have also tried by adding another **search criteria** inf `$filters2` however that seemed to be an OR statement.

The store code seems correct as no error is thrown unlike when I get the store code wrong. Using "default" similarly pulls both users. How do I just get the customers from the 1 store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Out of the box you can only get customers by store_id

[http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=**your](http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=store_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=**your) store id**&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]==

UPDATE

**This generates and AND conditi**on
[http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=5&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]==&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=email_value_here&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][condition_type]==](http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=store_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=5&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D==&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B1%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=email&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B1%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=email_value_here&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B1%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D==)

**This generates an "OR" condition**
[http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=5&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]==&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][field]=email&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][value]=email_value_here&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][1][condition_type]==](http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=store_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=5&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D==&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B1%5D%5Bfield%5D=email&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B1%5D%5Bvalue%5D=email_value_here&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B1%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D==)

Comment: What about if you wanted to add  a second condition like I suggested in my question. This is I think what my filter2 was trying but need the email condition also so matching email from just that store? When I added both those together I got all emails for that store like an OR statement when i want AND.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if you need any help. If you use the same filter group this will generate an "OR" condition. If you use this filter groups, like the UPDATE I just posted, this will generate an "AND" condition. Don't forget to upvote / mark as answer if the issue was solved ;)

Comment: Perfect, not played to much with search good thing to know! Shame couldn't do it just with URL that was what I was expecting but this is also fine!

Answer (score -1):

just a question, are you really sure that this method you are developing is the correct one and that there is no better choice for what you need?

Anyway, have you looked here?
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html

Cheers