# Magento 2 REST APIs fetch results by store code

Tags: magento2, orders, customer, rest-api, products

When i am trying to fetch the orders, & customers & products collection by using store code I am getting another store results aswell. Did any one facing the issue in the magento 2.4 version? please advise how to overcome this issue.

as per theattached screenshot below, there are two stores demo1 & demo2. Here i am trying to fetch the collections for demo1 store.

http://local.magento24.com/rest/demo1/V1/orders?searchCriteria

http://local.magento24.com/rest/demo1/V1/products?searchCriteria

http://local.magento24.com/rest/demo1/V1/customers/search?searchCriteria

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the below link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319009/search-customers-for-specific-store-magento-2-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue as you mentioned, I've checked on M2.4.2.

In order to get specific store order data try using below api

[http://local.magento24.com/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=your_store_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq](http://local.magento24.com/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=store_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=your_store_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5BconditionType%5D=eq)

where replace `your_store_id` with your demo1/demo2 store id. Thanks!